# How to include javascript on client side of node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm a beginner of node.js and javascript.

I want to include external javascript file in html code. Here is the html code, "index.html":

```
<script src="simple.js"></script>
```

And, here is the javascript code, "simple.js":

```
document.write('Hello');
```

When I open the "index.html" directly on a web browser(e.g. Google Chrome), It works.
("Hello" message should be displayed on the screen.)

However, when I tried to open the "index.html" via node.js http server, It doesn't work.
Here is the node.js file, "app.js":

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , fs = require('fs')

app.listen(8000);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}
```

("index.html", "simple.js" and "app.js" are on same directory.)
I started the http server. (by "bash$node app.js")
After then, I tried to connect "localhost:8000".
But, "Hello" message doesn't appear.

I think the "index.html" failed to include the "simple.js" on the http server.

How should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that nomatter what your browser requests, you return "index.html". So the browser loads your page and get's html. That html includes your script tag, and the browser goes asking node for the script-file. However, your handler is set up to ignore what the request is for, so it just returns the html once more.

Comment: I got a direction by your advice. I need to learn about the 'handler'. Thanks!

Comment: A quick tips. If you're using a reasonable browser, you should be able to see the requested and responded data fairly easily. Try clicking `F12` in your browser, and look for something named "network" or "request" (or similar, depends on browser).

Answer (score 22):

Alxandr is right. I will try to clarify more his answer.

It happens that you have to write a "router" for your requests. Below it is a simple way to get it working. If you look forward [www.nodebeginner.org](http://www.nodebeginner.org/) you will find a way of build a proper router.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {

    var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");

    response.writeHead(200);

    if(pathname == "/") {
        html = fs.readFileSync("index.html", "utf8");
        response.write(html);
    } else if (pathname == "/script.js") {
        script = fs.readFileSync("script.js", "utf8");
        response.write(script);
    }


    response.end();
}).listen(8888);

console.log("Listening to server on 8888...");
```

Comment: Timbó, thank you for the both _simple_ and _worked_ snippet!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working code.
There should be more cleaner simpler code, but this is very close to minimal.

This code suppose your index.html and other files are under /client dir.

Good luck.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require("url");
var path = require('path');
var mime = require('mime');

var log = console.log; 

var handler = function (req, res)
{
    var dir = "/client";
    var uri = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
    if (uri == "/")
    {
        uri = "index.html";
    }
    var filename = path.join(dir, uri);
    log(filename);
    log(mime.lookup(filename));
    fs.readFile(__dirname + filename,
        function (err, data)
        {
            if (err)
            {
                res.writeHead(500);
                return res.end('Error loading index.html');
            }
            log(data);
            log(filename + " has read");
            res.setHeader('content-type', mime.lookup(filename));
            res.writeHead(200);
            res.end(data);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your handler is hardcoded to always return the content of `/index.html`. You need to pay attention to the resource that is being requested and return the right one. (i.e. if the browser asks for `simple.js` then you need to give it `simple.js` instead of `index.html`).

Answer (score 1):

```
function contentType(ext) {
    var ct;

    switch (ext) {
    case '.html':
        ct = 'text/html';
        break;
    case '.css':
        ct = 'text/css';
        break;
    case '.js':
        ct = 'text/javascript';
        break;
    default:
        ct = 'text/plain';
        break;
    }

    return {'Content-Type': ct};
}

var PATH = 'C:/Users/DELL P26E/node_modules'
var http = require("http");
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require("url");
var path = require("path")
var fileName = "D:/index.html";
    
var server = http.createServer (function (request, response) {

var dir = "D:/";
var uri = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

if (uri == "/") {
    uri = "index.html";
}

var filename = path.join(dir, uri);

fs.readFile(filename,
    function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            response.writeHead(500);
            return response.end('Error loading index.html');
        }
                
        var ext = path.extname(filename)
        response.setHeader('content-type',contentType(ext));
        response.writeHead(200);
        response.end(data);
    });
}).listen(3000);
    
console.log('Server running on 8124') ;
```