# node.js index.html javascript function not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an '*index.html*' page that references a javascript file of mine, '*bargraph1.js*', that is in the same directory as *index.html*.  In the html file, I call a function in that js page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>D3 Test</title>

     <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.v4/d3.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="bargraph1.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>BarGraph</h2>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         barGraph(null, null, null, 30);
      </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

The file *bargraph1.js* contains one function '**barGraph()**' that uses d3 to render a bar graph.

If I open this file with 'file open' in my browser, it renders beautifully with no errors in the browser error console.

HOWEVER, if I try to serve the page from a nodejs server, the bar graph does not appear and the console shows '**barGraph not defined**'.  The h2 header preceeding it does show up, though.  (Actually I don't think it can find anything in any of the referenced .js files when served by the server).  Here's the server code:

```
var app  = require ('express')();
var http = require ('http').Server(app);
var io   = require ('socket.io')(http);

var pagePath = __dirname + '/index.html';
console.log('sending page ' + pagePath + '\'');
app.get ('/', function(req, res) { res.sendFile(pagePath); });

io.on ('connection', function(socket) {
   console.log ('\nsocket.id ' + socket.id + ' connected');

   socket.on ('disconnect', function() {
      console.log ('\nsocket.id ' + socket.id + ' disconnected');
   });
});

//===================================================
// set HTTP server to listen on port 3001
//===================================================

http.listen (3001, function() {
    console.log(' (3) http listening on *:3001 '); 
});
```

SO - obviously there is something different about how things get resolved (paths?) in these two different ways to show the html page with javascript.  I have been using this same bargraph1.js file many times in files opened locally in the browser so I am sure there are no syntax errors in it.

How can I get this file and the functions contained in it to work with a nodejs server?

Thanks

Comment: You don't have routes for the static files, so the browser is getting a 404 when trying to contact the server for them. You need to serve the script files statically from the server as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create routes for the URLs inside the `<script>` tags. Otherwise, when your browser requests those script files, it will get a 404 from the Node server (this doesn't happen when you just double-click the HTML file because your computer automatically serves those files using directories as URL paths). Since you're using Express now, try running

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '/')));
```

and then at the end instead of doing `http.listen`, run

```
app.listen(3001, process.env.IP || "0.0.0.0", function() {
    console.log(' (3) http listening on *:3001 '); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks - I eventually did find this information here, similar to the answer that you and others provided - I was just searching the wrong way!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722407/how-to-include-javascript-on-client-side-of-node-js