# load external .js file from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a simple HTML file, from which I want to load .js file. 
I have these files (files are in the same folder):

start.js

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, response) {
    fs.readFile('index.html', 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
        response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        response.write(data);
        response.end();
    });
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <script src="http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/build/three.min.js"></script>
       <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type= "text/javascript" src="./SetData.js"></script>
        <title>main project demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

and SetData.js

```
console.log("Its me");
```

Im using node.js, so I start my project with `node start.js`
In index.html I want to call local SetData.js file with

```
<script type= "text/javascript" src="./SetData.js"></script>
```

But nothing shows on web, only this error
[image]

I already tried to call .js file from another folder or call it from body part. Always the same error.
How can I load local .js file from HTML?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js quick file server (static files over HTTP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333790/node-js-quick-file-server-static-files-over-http)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code in your start.js with the following code. This has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722407/how-to-include-javascript-on-client-side-of-node-js)

```
var fs = require("fs");
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {

var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");

response.writeHead(200);

    if(pathname == "/") {
        html = fs.readFileSync("index.html", "utf8");
        response.write(html);
    } else if (pathname == "/SetData.js") {
        script = fs.readFileSync("SetData.js", "utf8");
        response.write(script);
    }
    response.end();
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```