# Cant find embedded script in HTML in nodemon

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

I am a newbie, experimenting with JS. I was trying to build a small Node.js app, with a JS script embedded in the index.html, but when I run nodemon, it returns 404 for the script and cant find it. The same html page with embedded script works fine with parcel. What am I doing wrong?

My app.js :

```
const express = require('express')
app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res, next)=>{
    
    res.sendFile('D:/Node.js Folder/My first project/views/index.html')
    
})

app.get('/add-user', (req, res, next)=>{
    
    res.sendFile('D:/Node.js Folder/My first project/views/add-user.html')
    
})

app.get('/show-user', (req, res, next)=>{
    
    res.sendFile('D:/Node.js Folder/My first project/views/show-users.html')
    
})

app.listen(3000)
```

HTML File :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    
</head>
<body class = "text-gray-400">
    
    <div>
        <div class = "text-3xl">
            <nav>
                <h1>
                    Hello! Welcome to the first page!
                </h1>
                <h1 class = "chat-notification-title">
                    Hello! Welcome to the first page!
                </h1>
                <form>
                    <label for="cname">Company Name</label><br>
                    <input type="text" id="cname" name="cname"><br>
                    <label for="ccode">Company Code</label><br>
                    <input type="text" id="ccode" name="ccode">
                  </form> 
                  <button class ='btn-submit' type = "submit">Add Record</button>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div><script src="../controller/controller-1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Embedded Script :

```
'use strict'


console.log(document)
const button = document.querySelector('.btn-submit')
console.log(button)
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    
    console.log('BUTTON PRESSED')
    alert("Pressed")
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you need to do is stop using absolute paths

for eg. `'D:/Node.js Folder/My first project/views/index.html'`

should be `./views/index.html`

assuming that the app.js file is in the same folder as the views folder.

The server on which you might deploy this code is not going to have the same path as your pc.

You also might wanna make a static folder and move your html, script (controller) folder inside that
and add the following line to the app.js

```
app.use('/', express.static('static'))

// or

app.use('/', express.static('./static'))
```

this way you won't have to serve the individual files like you are doing right now.

if you have the `src` for the embedded file set to `./controller/controller-1.js` it will work fine.

Comment: Edited my question to include code

Comment: Ok, I solved it by adding this to my app.js - 

app.get('/controller/controller-1.js', (req, res, next)=>{
    
    res.sendFile('D:/Node.js Folder/My first project/controller/controller-1.js')
    
})

Is there another way to get this done?

Comment: you need to stop using absolute paths ASAP

Comment: Ok, should I use path? 

const path = require('path');

module.exports = path.dirname(require.main.filename);

Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: No I am simply say You need to use canonical paths (these are relative paths and does not depend on the systems file structure only the file structure of the directory you will deploy on the server). I have explained this in the answer.

Comment: `Ok, should I use path? ` Path is used for a better way to modify paths in NodeJS. for which You can use normal string but why would you.

Comment: I explained it as well, you should use `res.sendFile(path.resolve("../client/dist/index.html"));` and `import * as path from "path";`

Answer (score 0):

Nodemon are supposed to be used on the server side, often running an express or similar server.
`parcel serve` is what you are supposed to use on the client side (without server), to serve the html files directly.

You should also not use paths to your own disk. Luckily when the project is running it creates a dist folder with the same files. You are meant to link those to paths in code. Ie on `res.sendFile` you should write  `res.sendFile(path.resolve("../client/dist/index.html"))` or `res.sendFile(path.resolve("../dist/views/index.html))`

You import path as `import * as path from "path"`

If you want to use it with a server, then you should do this:

Client json "dev" should `parcel watch index.html`, and server "dev" should `nodemon server.js`.
Both these scripts are supposed to be run in the root package.json file, with concurrently, allowing them to run simultaneously

```
"dev": "concurrently npm:server:dev npm:client:dev",
"server:dev": "cd server && npm run dev",
"client:dev": "cd client && npm run dev",
```

In the server file, you should then do something like this:

```
import express from "express"; //import express
const app = express(); // use express
app.use(express.static("../client/dist/")); // allows express to server static files

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.method === "GET" && !req.path.startsWith("/api")) {
    return res.sendFile(path.resolve("../client/dist/index.html"));
  } else {
    next();
  }
}); // checks if url is trying to reach an api, if not it returns the file you are looking for

const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
  console.log("Server started on http://localhost:" + server.address().port);
}); // starts server and logs the localhost url
```

You are then meant to access your site from the server side, and every time you change the server, nodemon will restart the server for you, and every time you change the client, parcel will do the same

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding this to my app.js :

app.get('/controller/controller-1.js', (req, res, next)=>{

```
res.sendFile('D:/Node.js Folder/My first project/controller/controller-1.js')
```

})

Help from this thread : [How to include javascript on client side of node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722407/how-to-include-javascript-on-client-side-of-node-js)

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Look at my answer, you are not meant to run from your own drive, but the dist folder. This is so Heroku for instance, and other external services can also access the files

Comment: Yes that works! Thank you so much. This is a much easier way to do it. Thank you!!